# Borders not showing in CSS

Tags: css

So I have a problem with bottom border not showing on my elements. When I inspect the element it's not overwritten by anything and there is also no error being shown.

I wrote this poorly.
So I need just the bottom border, others should not be seen.

```css
#top .input-text,
  #top input[type="text"],
  #top input[type="email"],
  #top input[type="tel"],
  #top textarea,
  #top select {
  background: #fff;
  font: 1em 'rajdhani', sans-serif;
  border-style: solid;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<input type="email"><br>
    <p>Something</p>
    <input type="text"><br>
    <p>Something2</p>
    <input type="tel"><br>
```

What happens on the website tho is that all the borders are hidden. I need to set border: 0; first to overwrite the default border.

Comment: remove `border:0;`

Comment: whre do you need a border?

Comment: Use border-color: [colour]; border-width: 0 0 1px 0; and dump border: 0;

Comment: use border-bottom: 1px solid;

Comment: mention your expected output. you need border or not. what you need @Mark

Answer (score 1):

```css
.input-text {
  background: #fff;
  font: 1em 'rajdhani', sans-serif;
  border-style: solid;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" class="input-text"><br>
<p>Something</p>
<input type="text" class="input-text"><br>
<p>Something2</p>
<input type="tel" class="input-text"><br>
```

Use `border-bottom:1px solid #000;` instead of `border-bottom: 1px;`

Comment: @Mark It will work. It even worked in the code snippet. Try removing `#top`

Answer (score 1):

Add a container div and give the id 'top'. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwk442hx/)

```
<div id="top">
  <input type="email">
  <br>
  <p>Something</p>
  <input type="text">
  <br>
  <p>Something2</p>
  <input type="tel">
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the `border: 0` css rule

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
```